# How to Keep the ScrollPosition while inserting items at the Front?

Tags: flutter, dart

#### What I want

I want to create a behavior like Twitter App. So I scroll to the top of my list, I use a `CupertinoSliverRefreshControl` to load new posts and want to place them on top of my current shown list with keeping my ScrollPosition.

#### What my code looks like

To make usage of the `CupertinoSliverRefreshControl` I need to use `slivers` in a `CustomScrollView`. `onRefresh` I load new posts and add the old posts to it:

```
final _scrollController = ScrollController(keepScrollOffset: true);


return CustomScrollView(
  controller: _scrollController
  physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(parent: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics()),
  slivers: <Widget>[
    CupertinoSliverRefreshControl(
      onRefresh: () {
        // loading new posts. I set state with blocBuilder but for easiness I show it with setState here:
        setState(() { posts = List.from(newPosts..addAll(posts)); })
      }
    ),
    SliverList(
      delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate((context, index) {
        return PostCard(posts[index]);
      },
      childCount: posts.length)
    )
  ]
);
```

#### What my problem is

Saving the `ScrollPosition` with a `ScrollController` is not working because it always saves the offset to the top and not to the bottom. In my case, the offset to the top will change by loading new posts.

#### What I've tried

I also tried to build the old posts and the new posts in two different `SliverLists`. To the `SliverList` with old posts, I added a key and set the `center` of my `CustomScrollView`to this key. Doing so crashes my `CupertinoSliverRefreshControl`.

Also, I cannot just use the list reversed because I want a loading into the other direction as well in a further development state.

Comment: Hello @Sonius! I'm exactly in the same place as you almost two years after. Did you find a way to avoid the jumpy listview when updating the scroll with the controller? I've found myself exactly in the same place as you when you wrote `So in a short frame it will jump to the top of the list and back to my position right after. The position after that jump is right`. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`ScrollController.position`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollController/position.html) for this:

```dart
// You will need to place the following code snippets in appropriate locations.
double extentAfter;

// Save the current offset from the bottom:
extentAfter = _scrollController.position.extentAfter;


// After your loading is done, you can apply the saved extentAfter:
_scrollController.jumpTo(_scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent - extentAfter);
```

I do not exactly know how your setup works, but I could imagine that saving the `extentAfter` can be done in a listener of your `ScrollController` (because you want to have the latest `extentAfter` before the new items are inserted) and jumping to the "new" position when rebuilding the scroll view.

You can not call `jumpTo` when rebuilding by supplying a new `ScrollController`:

```dart
// Update your scroll controller with the new position.
_scrollController = ScrollController(
  initialScrollOffset: _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent - extentAfter
);
```

Comment: Tried it works but is not optimal. I have to call _scrollController.jumpTo() after the rebuild. So in a short frame it will jump to the top of the list and back to my position right after. The position after that jump is right :)

Comment: Or to specify my comment: Is there a way to call jumpTo right after the list was created?

Comment: good idea but _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent will not be updated before rebuilding because it is still assigned to the old list.

Comment: @Sonius In that case you will have to calculate your new `maxScrollExtent` yourself. This should be fairly easy if your items have a fixed size.

Comment: They are not. But I think I can work with it, thank you!

Comment: @Sonius the solution you are looking for is here, there is no delay or jumping, see Arsenii Burov answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52180947/prepend-list-view-items-while-maintaining-scroll-view-offset-in-flutter