# Tapping again on same tab its bring me top of the screen

Tags: flutter, user-interface, scroll, bottomnavigationview

I have four tabs in bottomnavigation, i want to build functionally like Instagram when I tap on the home screen it brings the top of the home page For ex: I m on the home screen I scroll on the home screen then go to the second tab again come to the home screen by a tap on the bottom navigation screen is middle of the scroll but I tap again on home tap icon it will automatically scroll to top. I m using `indexStack` for `bottomnavigation` Any one has any idea about it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [ScrollController](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollController-class.html).

In the ListView or SingleChildScrollView (or whatever other scrollable widget) add controller.

```
final ScrollController scrollController = ScrollController();

...

SingleChildScrollView(
 controller: scrollController,
 child: ...
)
```

Then if you want to get back to the top of the scrollview you can call

```
scrollController.animateTo(
 scrollController.position.minScrollExtent,
 duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
 curve: Curves.easeOut,
)
```

To get this functionality only on the second tap of the bottomappbar icon you can check if the index is equal to the current page index.

You can find a working example in the BottomNavigationBar api page: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BottomNavigationBar-class.html#material.BottomNavigationBar.3

Answer (score 1):

The best and most easiest way to do this without any scroll controller or anything would be to use the `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin`

[AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin Docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin-mixin.html)

Another question on stack overflow:
[SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60292911/how-to-get-flutter-scrollcontroller-to-save-position-of-listview-builder-when)